# Cannot find module rimraf in docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

When i try to run my node project which uses rimraf, in a docker container, I get the error that module rimraf cannot be found. It is installed and can be found in my package.json. If i run my app locally, everything works fine.
Error log:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'rimraf'
node_1     |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:571:15)
node_1     |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:497:25)
node_1     |     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626:17)
node_1     |     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
node_1     |     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/controllers/products.js:5:16)
node_1     |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:678:30)
node_1     |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:10)
node_1     |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:589:32)
node_1     |     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:528:12)
node_1     |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:3)
node_1     |     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626:17)
node_1     |     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
node_1     |     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/expressRoutes/productRoutes.js:6:26)
node_1     |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:678:30)
node_1     |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:10)
node_1     |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:589:32)
```

my dockerfile:

```
    FROM node

    # Create a directory where our app will be placed
    RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

    # Change directory so that our commands run inside this new directory
    WORKDIR /usr/src/app

    # Copy dependency definitions
    COPY package.json /usr/src/app

    # Install dependecies
    RUN npm install

    # Get all the code needed to run the app
    COPY . /usr/src/app

    # Expose the port the app runs in
    EXPOSE 4000

    # Serve the app
    CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Any help/suggestions why this happens?
Github link: https://github.com/isaacs/rimraf/issues/171

My docker-compose.yml as asked.

```
version: '2'

  services:
    node:
            image: some-private-repo/node_application:latest
            ports:
            - "4000:4000"
            links:
            - mongo
            environment:
            - MONGO_URL=mongodb://mongo:27017/mydb
            networks:
            - network
            depends_on:
            - mongo
    mongo:
            image: mongo:latest
            ports:
            - "27017:27017"
            networks:
            - network
```

networks:
        network:
                driver: bridge

Comment: How did you run this image? Are you sure `COPY . /usr/src/app` isn't overwriting anything related to the modules?

Comment: I used docker build to build an image from this and then run my application with docker-compose

Comment: My application has always worked correctly in docker. but now with the addition of the rimraf module it doesnt work anymore.

Comment: Show us your docker-compose file.

Comment: @emix see updated question :)

Comment: Did you try rebuilding the image with `--no-cache` option?

Comment: Silly check. Is there rimraf in your package.json?

Comment: @whites11 somehow it wasnt. yesterday i installed it like 2 times but when i checked this morning rimraf was indeed not in my package.json
I ran npm install rimraf, it showed up. built a docker container from it and it worked. thanks for this silly check :D

Comment: Sometimes simple answers are the right ones :)